# Restricting a layer in Maven Project

Tags: java, maven, design-patterns, architecture

We are developing Service Oriented Architecture in Model, DataAccess, Service and Services API layering Architecture, where as I have implemented following layered architecture in place for dependency flow.

WEB Layer 
          |
SERVICES API 
   |
SERVICE 
   |
DATAACCESS 
   |
MODEL

Now I want to restricted the method calls of each of the layers at one level. Like: Methods of Model can be accessible at Data Access level but not at service, services API and Web Layer. This will be same for Data Access, Service and Services API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create separate Interfaces for each layer communication.
eg:

Create one interface for communication between web layer and service api layer.
expose only those methods that you wish too. Both of them will have there own implementation.

Create another interface for communication between service layer service.
expose only those methods that you wish too. Both of them will have there own implementation and so on.

Note : You will have to convert from one interface to another.

Comment: I agreed upon on your point but i do have following restrictions here. 1. My whole implementation classes are bound in interface and implementation class mode. So i need intact with interface and implementation class structure. 2. I use Autowiring for binding the implementation in classes.

Comment: Look into google juice ... they help you bind 2 implementations to the same interface....